# How to apply another background layer under text

Tags: css

CSS community, if this question has been asked I'll be happy to close it.

Here is the problem: you have an element with a background, and want to add another background on top of the first one, for instance with some transparency. The text of the element is static and should appear "above" the backgrounds.

Is there any way to do that **only with CSS**? I know that I can dynamically add other elements etc but I'm looking for a way to do this with style rules only.

Please run this snippet to see what I have in mind. Ideally I would have a way to put this `:before` style in between my text and its own background.

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #c8e289;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>Text Barely Visible</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `z-index: 0` to the element, and `z-index: -1` to the pseudo element.

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #c8e289;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>Text Barely Visible</div>
```

---

Or you can go the multi background route:

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 50%, transparent 50%), #c8e289;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>Text Barely Visible</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly it! I thought I tried z-index already but apparently I didn't, thanks!

Comment: You can try with multiple backgrounds as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, although I cannot alter the initial css, jsut add new rules on top of it (and I don't know the original background color). But that could serve the comminity

Answer (score 2):

Define both backgrounds using pseudo elements, and put them behind the parent with negative z-indexes.

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
div:before, div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}
div:after {
  background: #c8e289;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}
div:before {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>Text Barely Visible</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I might accept this answer eventually but this requires me to use JS to "move" the background of each element first (I don't have control of the elements initially). All I have is a class added to the element so ideally new CSS rules on top of what's there would be enough.

Comment: @floribon why would you have to use JS, couldn't you just write CSS that overrides the current styles?

Comment: in your answer you moved the background property of the element to its `:after` pseudo-class, which as is requires js.

Comment: @floribon no it doesn't... everything is CSS. If you can modify the site's CSS, you would just make the change I did - no JS. But if you can't modify the CSS and you can only overwrite the existing CSS, just undo the div background with `background: none;`, then add it to the pseudo element with the rules I used.

Comment: Setting the background to none will remove the first layer. When you say "add it to the pseudo element" you assume that I know what was this background value that I just removed, but I don't. But in fact there is no need to remove that background, I invite you to look at the accepted answer

Comment: @floribon *"you assume that I know what was this background value that I just removed, but I don't."* Ah, yeah I am making that assumption because you didn't say that in your OP. This is a CSS only solution, but not with that requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just need to mess with the z-index!

You could set your parent container to position: relative; z-index: 1. for example.

Then, you have a child which will act as the other background, position this absolutely with a z-index of 2.

Then finally, your text wrap in it's own tags, such as a p tag, position it relative with a z-index of 3.

Here's a code example:

```
<div class="parent-bg">
    <div class="parent-bg__child-bg"></div>
    <p class="parent-bg__child-text">Text</p>
</div>

.parent-bg {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 20rem;
}

.parent-bg__child-bg {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.parent-bg__child-text {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 3;
   color: black;
}
```

Here's a pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggJLoa

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but again I'd like to find a way to do this only by adding CSS to the targeted element, without the need for adding new elements etc.

Answer (score 1):

you have done absolutely correct only thing you need to add z-index;

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #c8e289;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div>text is visible here</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the right answer! You posted it at the same time as someone else and I tossed a coin to accept one

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple background separate by commas. Or you can send pseudoelement behind the parent element with `z-index: -1` (only works if parent element dont have a declared z-index).